# Grouping by a column and assigning different aggregation function for a certain column that is used in a group by

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a `df`:

```
field           category            2022-01-10      2022-01-17      2022-01-24    2022-01-31 
A               Chair               50              100             200           150
B               Chair               75              15              57            75   
C               Chair               0.57            0.64            0.4           0.47
A               Table               50              100             200           150
B               Table               75              15              57            75   
C               Table               0.57            0.64            0.4           0.47
A               Mirror              50              100             200           150
B               Mirror              75              15              57            75   
C               Mirror              0.57            0.64            0.4           0.47
```

I am trying to group by `field` or simply drop the `category` column and aggregate the values for each week so that the result would look like this:

```
field       2022-01-10      2022-01-17      2022-01-24    2022-01-31 
A           50+50+50        100+100+100     200+200+200   150+150+150
B           75+75+75        15+15+15        57+57+57      75+75+75
C           np.mean([0.57, 0.57, 0.57])     # each weeks average of field C
```

For fields `A & B` each week I would sum up the values for that week in different categories, but for field `C` I want the average.

I tried:
`df.groupby(['field']).agg({'A':sum, 'B':sum, 'C'.np.mean})` but this of course does not work because the fields arethe thing that's being grouped by and not the column.

I believe this problem can be sorted by somehow dropping an `category` column and then transforming the values based on `field` column but I am not sure how that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dict of functions to apply then flat your dataframe and group by `field` and `variable` (dates) columns. Use the first index of `groupby` to get the right function. Finally reshape your dataframe.

```
aggfuncs = {'A': lambda x: np.sum(x),
            'B': lambda x: np.sum(x),
            'C': lambda x: np.mean(x)}

out = df.melt(['field', 'category']).groupby(['field', 'variable'])['value'] \
        .apply(lambda x: aggfuncs[x.name[0]](x)).unstack() \
        .rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
print(out)

# Output
  field  2022-01-10  2022-01-17  2022-01-24  2022-01-31
0     A      150.00      300.00       600.0      450.00
1     B      225.00       45.00       171.0      225.00
2     C        0.57        0.64         0.4        0.47
```

Answer (score 1):

{A, B} and {C} require different handling, so we can handle them separately

```
pd.concat([
    df[df['field'].isin(['A', 'B'])).groupby('field').sum(), #for AB
    df[df['field']=='C'].groupby('field').mean(),  #for C
])
```

Comment: This creates rows for each date column for some reason.

Comment: I ended up using `df[df['field']=='C'].groupby('field').mean()` instead in the second part.

Comment: My bad. Please try again

Comment: Yes. Agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to approach the problem:

```
s = df.set_index('field').select_dtypes(np.number)

out = s.drop('C').groupby(level=0).sum()
out.loc['C', :] = s.loc['C'].mean()
```

Result:

```
print(out)

       2022-01-10  2022-01-17  2022-01-24  2022-01-31
field                                                
A          150.00      300.00       600.0      450.00
B          225.00       45.00       171.0      225.00
C            0.57        0.64         0.4        0.47
```

Comment: Does the `.select_dtypes(np.number)` takes everything but the floats like `0.57`? Asking because this solution is clear but might be limited to what the `df` is.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis `select_dtypes(np.number)` will select the numeric only columns thus it will automatically drop the `category` column.